# How to create a GWT DialogBox, but not show it

Tags: java, gwt

All the examples for DialogBox does something like

```
void someFn()
{
    DialogBox box = new DialogBox();
    box.show();
}
```

but I want to create it earlier like

```
private DialogBox box = new DialogBox();

void someFn()
{
    box.show();
}
```

The problem is that it shows up directly without waiting for any action.
Any ideas how this can be handled?

The dialog box is created by a function called from the constructor as

```
private DialogBox makeMenu() {
    DialogBox ret = new DialogBox(true);
    FlowPanel f = new FlowPanel();
    f.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("minWidth", "350px");

    // Add stuff
    f.add(...)

    ret.setWidget(f);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Just creating a `DialogBox` does not show it. What does your `MyDialogBox` do in the constructor, probably calling `show()/center()`?

Comment: No, I've even tried calling hide() in it just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer was a step up. You should never add a DialogBox to a Panel and I did that as

```
FlowPanel container = new FlowPanel();
container.add(menu);
```

Stupid mistake, but not something you look for first.